# Arduino MKR 10100 control DC Motor

Tags: motor, transistor, iot, mkr1000, mkr1010

Thank you for reading my post. I have been stuck on this for several weeks now! I am trying to turn ON/OFF a DC motor from Arduino IOT Cloud. I have set up the cloud and added the switch. Everything works well with an LED: it lights on and off as needed, but the motor does not turn on or off. Below is the circuit I have set up.

[image: Circuit Design]

My circuit specs are as follows:

1. I'm not using a UNO as the image illustrates, rather I'm using an [Arduino MKR WiFi 1010](https://www.seeedstudio.com/ARDUINO-MKR-WiFi-1010-p-46.html), but the connections of the pins are exactly the same: LED at PIN 3 and Motor at 7.
2. The diode I am using is [1N4001](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BTY8FD2).
3. The transistor I'm using is [TIP120](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07LG2C3MY).
4. The motor I'm using is [5V DC Motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P18SQSR).
5. 270 Ohm resistor on the transistor circuit and 220 Ohm on the LED circuit.

The Arduino code I made is as follows:

```
#include "thingProperties.h"

#define LED_PIN 3
#define MOTOR_PIN 7

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MOTOR_PIN, OUTPUT);

  setDebugMessageLevel(2); // For debugging of cloud integration
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1500);

  initProperties(); // initialize cloud properties
  ArduinoCloud.begin(ArduinoIoTPreferredConnection); // Connect to cloud
}

void loop() {
  ArduinoCloud.update(); // Update cloud background services
}

void onMotorChange() {
  if (motor) {
    // Motor & LED ON
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
  } else {
    // Motor & LED OFF
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_PIN, LOW);
  }
}
```

All my setup seems to be be correct, but it just is not working. I have researched a lot but to no avail. I have tested with a different motor just to be sure, but it also does not work. I'm not sure where I have made a mistake.

Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: never use an arduino as a power supply ... there is a good chance that the arduino will become an expensive fuse

Comment: Thank you for the tip, i do not have an external power supply that's why i resorted to the 5V pin. in regards to my question do you see why am facing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i managed to solve it, the issue was actually my circuit wiring. Below is an image with the correct setup for the transistor or MOSFET.

[image]

I have changed the TIP120 to RFP30N06LE as [VE7JRO](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/37523/ve7jro) suggested:

> The TIP120 is a poor choice because of the approximate 10% - 14% voltage drop across it. Try the circuit with a logic level, low Rds MOSFET.

but that with the circuit in question does not work. I have not tested the circuit attached with this answer using a TIP120 but i suspect it would work as well.
Finally i added a 9V battery as [jsotola](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/40318/jsotola) suggested:

> never use an arduino as a power supply ... there is a good chance that the arduino will become an expensive fuse

but i have not tested using the 5V Arduino pin again i suspect it would work as well.

### Bonus:

If anyone was wondering how i made these images i used [TinkerCAD](https://www.tinkercad.com)

Thank you all

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 1):

The TIP120 is a poor choice because of the approximate 10% - 14% voltage drop across it. Try the circuit with a logic level, low Rds MOSFET.

For a more in-depth answer, please see this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/388468/165322

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103629/discussion-on-answer-by-ve7jro-arduino-mkr-10100-control-dc-motor).

Comment: Hello VE7RO, hope you have been great! thank you for your input from before, i got everything working.
Now am working on making a PCB of it but i couldnt been to find an SMT version/replacement for the RFP30N06LE, i was wondering if this would work https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMV15UNEA.pdf since my aplication does not really reach the limit of 60 V or 30 A, while this provides good Rds, Thanks!